# H2O (0xData) data frame back to R data.frame

Tags: r, jetty, h2o

If I start H2O using Jetty HashLoginService (i.e. `-hash_login -login_conf realm.properties`) in order to protect my H2O instance with password, I cannot convert H2O object into R object.

For example in the following `as.data.frame` will not work, as if would work if I didn't use HashLoginService:

```
> require(h2o)
> h2o.init(port     = 54324,  startH2O = F, 
           password = "pass", username = "uname")
 Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         5 days 15 hours 
    H2O cluster version:        3.9.1.3405 
    H2O cluster name:           uname 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   22.19 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  2 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54324 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    R Version:                  R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)

> packageVersion("h2o")
[1] ‘3.9.1.3405’

> df  <- data.frame(a = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2),
                    b = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9))

> h2o_df <- as.h2o(df, "h2o_df")
  |==============================================================================| 100%

> head(h2o_df)
     a    b
1  0.2  0.1
2  0.3  0.1
3  0.1  0.7
4  0.5  0.3
5  0.1  0.2
6  0.2  0.9

> class(h2o_df)
[1] "H2OFrame"

> as.data.frame(h2o_df)
                                                                X.html.
1                                                                <head>
2  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1/>
3                                 <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
4                                                               </head>
5                                                                <body>
6                                              <h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
7                      <p>Problem accessing /3/DownloadDataset. Reason:
8                                       <pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
9                       <hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
10                                                                     
11                                                                     
12                                                                     
13                                                                     
14                                                                     
15                                                                     
16                                                                     
17                                                                     
18                                                                     
19                                                                     
20                                                                     
21                                                                     
22                                                                     
23                                                                     
24                                                                     
25                                                                     
26                                                                     
27                                                                     
28                                                                     
29                                                                     
30                                                              </body>
31                                                              </html>
Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  cols = 1 != length(data) = 11
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

---

**UPDATE**

This is a bug and you can track it here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-2968

Comment: are you passing the `username` and `password` parameters to `h2o.init()`?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Yes!  I edited the question.

Comment: seems it might be a bug in `as.data.frame` (looks like it might not be using the credentials) - will consult the the team and get back to you!

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk since I needed a solution right now, I wrote a workaround, see my answer below. It might be helpful for the developer team fixing the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far seems to be a bug.

In [`as.data.frame.H2OFrame`](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/h2o-package/R/frame.R) function `getURL` (from `RCurl` package) is called to retrieve the data from H2O server.

This function is used without passing any credentials.

One workaround would be to alter this function and replace `getURL(url)` with

```
ttt <- getURL(url, userpwd=paste0(conn@username,':',conn@password), httpauth = 1L)
```

Or check if username is given use the latter otherwise use the former.

A complete example how to use it is given [here](https://github.com/a-ghorbani/notebooks/blob/master/H2O/examples/H2O_as.data.frame_authentication_problem.R).